# Не выводит результат Lazarus

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

В Lazarus при нажатии зеленой кнопочки 'play' не появляеться консоль с результатом.
Это случилось после перехода с виндовс на линукс.
Советы из гугла не помогают ( пробовал на двух языках ).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вручную открыть окно `View > Debug Windows > Console In/Output` (или `Terminal Output` в старых версиях Lazarus):

[image: View > Debug Windows > Console In/Output]